# PowerShell5.1のスクリプトでStart/Stop-Transcriptでログを保存する時、 実行したコマンド自体をログに書き込みたい

Tags: powershell

PowerShell5.1のスクリプトでStart/Stop-Transcriptでログを保存する時、
実行したコマンド自体をログに書き込むことはできないでしょうか。

例えば

```
Start-Transcript
Write-Host "Hello World"
Stop-Transctipt
```

このスクリプトを実行したとき出力されるログファイルは

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell トランスクリプト開始
(中略)
**********************
トランスクリプトが開始されました。出力ファイル:（略）
HelloWorld
**********************
Windows PowerShell トランスクリプト終了
終了時刻: （略）
**********************
```

と保存されますが、私の希望は実行コマンドもログに保存することです。
つまり以下のようになってほしいです。

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell トランスクリプト開始
(中略)
**********************
トランスクリプトが開始されました。出力ファイル:（略）
PS>Write-Host "Hello World"
HelloWorld
**********************
Windows PowerShell トランスクリプト終了
終了時刻: （略）
**********************
```

試したこととして、`Set-PSDebug -Trace 1`を記載してみましたが、ストリームには似たような形で表示されるのですが、ログには一切表示されませんでした。

(追記)追加要件になりますが、エビデンス収集に使用したい為、実行コマンドと出力結果を順序通り出力したいと考えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PowerShell5.1のスクリプトでStart/Stop-Transcriptでログを保存する時、
> 実行したコマンド自体をログに書き込むことはできないでしょうか。

`Start/Stop-Transcript`でログを書く方法ではありませんが、スクリプトを`powershell‘に読み込ませて実行する方法はいかがでしょうか？

スクリプト q.ps1

```
Write-Host "Hello World"
```

実行方法

```
type .\q.ps1 | powershell -File -  > log.txt
```

log.txtの内容

```
PS D:\junc\ps> Write-Host "Hello World"
Hello World
PS D:\junc\ps>
```

Comment: この方針で検証した結果、以下のコードへ改良して、それを導入することにしました。  `Get-Content .\q.ps1|Select-String "#" -NotMatch|powershell|Out-File log.txt -Encoding UTF8` 以下解説です。①typeはpowershellコマンドレットに置き換えてGet-Contentとしました。機能的には同じです②元スクリプトに#コメントが含まれていると、そのまま表示されてしまう為、Select-Stringにて除外しています。③>にてリダイレクトした場合、出力ファイルはUTF16になってしまうため、Out-FIleに置き換え、エンコードオプションを追加しています。[スクリプト側について]コード間に空白行を入れた場合、コードと出力結果が交互に表示され、空白行なしの場合コードが連続で表示されてから出力結果が表示されます。見やすいほうを選択して使用するのがよいと思いました。以上が検証結果です。結果としてすっきり収まる方法が見つかったと思います。皆様ご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

> PowerShell5.1のスクリプトでStart/Stop-Transcriptでログを保存する時、
> 実行したコマンド自体をログに書き込むことはできないでしょうか。

下記のフォーラムによると、PowerShell5.1と5.0の不具合によりコマンド自体をログに書き込むことができないようです。
[Start-Transcript コマンドレットでデバッグ ログが出力されない](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/ja-JP/55c4b802-d01f-413f-8b72-041da82c8ca2/starttranscript)

ちなみに力技でスクリプトを保存する方法として、[PowerShell スクリプト ブロックのログ記録を有効にする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/wmf/whats-new/script-logging?view=powershell-7.2)方法を使って、全スクリプトログを強制的にイベントログとして保存する方法があります。
上記のリンク先を引用します。

> ログ記録は、 [管理用テンプレート] -> [Windows コンポーネント] -> [Windows PowerShell] の [PowerShell スクリプト ブロックのログ記録を有効にする] グループ ポリシー設定で有効にします。

ログ記録を参照するには「ファイル名を指定して実行」→「eventvwr.msc」などでイベントビューアを開き、左側ツリーで「アプリケーションとサービス ログ > Microsoft > Windows > PowerShell > Operational」を選択します。
右側のリストで対象のイベントを選択することで、下記のような形で実行結果を得られます。
ただし実行結果は保存されません。

```
Scriptblock テキストを作成しています (1 個中 1 個目):
Write-Host "Hello World"
```

下記のPowerShellスクリプトで10分以内のイベントを取得することもできます。

```
Get-WinEvent Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational | where Id -eq 4104 | where TimeCreated -ge $(date).AddMinutes(-10) | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap
```

Comment: Powershell7.2.4を導入して検証してみましたが、結果実行コマンド自体のログ出力はできておりませんでした。(Set-PSDebug -Trace 1を含め)  フォーラムの中身自体がだいぶ古いようですので、検討されないまま放置されたんですかね。  "力技"の方も参考にさせていただき、試してみましたが、希望したものではないようです。  エビデンス収集の為に実行コマンドと出力結果を順序通り出力してくれると助かるのですが。  引き続きアイデアを募集したいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

もし「絶対に実行した記録でなければいけない」という考えがあったとしても、その部分を妥協できて、人間が見て識別できるような何かがあれば良いのであれば、実行予定のコマンドとパラメータを表す文字列として事前に表示するスクリプトの行を追加する方法で代替出来るのでは？

例えばこんな風に記述してみるとか：

```
Start-Transcript
Write-Host "PS>Write-Host ""Hello World"""
Write-Host "Hello World"
Stop-Transcript
```

良くあるようにカレントディレクトリも表示するプロンプトならば以下のようにすれば良いでしょう。

```
Write-Host "PS $PWD>Write-Host ""Hello World"""
```

---

その後続けて調べていたらこんな記事を見つけました。
[PowerShell script, showing commands run](https://serverfault.com/q/102098)
承認された回答はありませんが、この行が応用できるかもしれません。
スクリプトファイルの内容を読み込んでパイプに流し、`invoke-expression`で実行するという形でしょうか。

> ```
> get-content foo.ps1|foreach-object{$_;invoke-expression "$_"}
> ```

試しに質問の3行をスクリプトにして実行してみたら、`Write-Host`の行もファイルに書き出されました。

ただし回答には複数行に分かれた記述は失敗すると書かれています。他にも色々と制約は出てきそうですね。

> The problem with the above is that if you have multi-line commands like this:
>
> ```
> foreach($proc in $procs){
>   $proc.processname
> }
> ```
>
> The above will fail with my example above if that's placed in foo.ps1 with that structure...

試してみてください。

Comment: 確かに方法の一つとして考えてはいましたが、その方法はデメリットが大きいように感じていました。①コード量が倍になり、見づらい＝点検しにくい(条件分岐などを省くことで少し減らすことはできますが)②修正箇所が発生した場合、2か所を修正しなくてはならない  現状の方法としては最有力かと思いましたが、最終手段にしたいです。往生際が悪いですが、まだ他に綺麗にまとまるアイデアがある方を募集します。

Comment: 追記分について検証してみましたが、確かに複数行の実行に失敗しますね。スクリプトの各行を1行ずつ読み込んで実行する動作になるためか、例えば`If{改行}`となったとき、ブロックが渡されず、エラーになるようです。